# Windows registry key to prevent automatic drivers installation?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I'm looking for a simple method to prevent Windows Update from installing drivers automatically. Exactly these steps:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2500967
Is there any method to do these steps just by modifying registry keys? Or even by doing it with help of a simple bat file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found an answer. The key I was looking for is located here:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DriverSearching]
"SearchOrderConfig"=dword:00000000
```

To add this values to our registry, we can use that command in our batch file:

```
REGEDIT /S NameOfOurRegFile.reg
```

Comment: I had turned off automatic windows updates to prevent it from getting newer Samsung drivers which prevented it from recognizing the device, but it seemed to have no effect and I periodically kept having to reinstall the drivers, restart the computer, turn off internet access and then plug in the device. I was hoping this registry change would help, but when I investigated it turned out to already have that value.

Comment: @WindowsWeenie Did you check if your changes has been properly applied? Please change a key as I described, restart your machine immediately and then follow [these steps](http://www.microcentertech.com/tech_center/DB/read_article.php?faqid=./HowTos/HOW5006661B.htm) to check if it was correctly disabled (in last step you should have _No, let me choose what to do_ selected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a registry key, but why not change the windows update to download, but not install.  Then you can review the updates and use right-click-hide to hide the driver updates.

I like to see the driver updates because that lets me know that I might want to go to the vendor site to look at the real driver info and decide if I need it or not.  I then only install the driver (from the vendors site) if there are changes I need.

And since I have hidden it in update, I don't get bothered again until a new driver comes out.

Just a thought (vs. hacking your registry.)

One other consideration.  In some cases, a registry hack might have some side consequences that confound you late when you can't figure out why something you thought should work, doesn't.  Most support options don't consider registry hacks when trying to figure out why something doesn't work...

I can't comment, so here are some things to consider.
What you want to do will possibly look very much like a virus that wants to prevent things from being fixed.  So if you do find a way, I strongly encourage you to test it with a number of AV apps - and then register it with them so they don't add it later.

You do have an option to check the version of the drivers in use for given hardware items.  Then, if your app sees a new driver, it can at least warn the user that a new driver was installed (and log that fact) and to roll the update back if they have problems.

Comment: To learn how to use registry key in batch type `reg /?` in cmd

Comment: Well, MS published some drivers updates that are incompatible with our hardware. It just prevents it from running. We're looking for a solution to make an app, that will disable downloading these in future and will prevent WU from installing its own drivers.